# how is designed classic e-commerce database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, e-commerce

I would like to ask you how does like e-commerce database look. I just started making e-shop in php and I would like to know how should I design my database (tables). I've already table with something like `user ID | User name | Name | Surname | address | login | password(MD5) | e-mail | registration datetime | last login datetime`. I was thinking about to store IP's but I think that's better to add function for suspend account. Also do you mean is it better to store users, admins, employees datas in same table or is it better make them separates?

Thank You

Comment: Why don't you use a ready-to-go commerce solution?  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_shopping_cart_software

Comment: Because it is a school project, whole code must be done by myself.

Comment: I would have the following database tables:

customers (or users)

orders (which would have a user_id to link to a user)


order_lines (which contains individual items for an order and is linked by an order_id) field.

What kind of database are you using because I would be happy to provide an example schema as an answer.

Comment: Go read up on Database normalization. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @MartinHohenberg: Yes I know this, I've address in table which fulfill 1NF, I just shorted my example of table (specially address).

Comment: @wiseguysonly I'm using WampServer with installed PHP 5.4.3 and MySQL 5.5.24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope [this](http://wiki.opencarthelp.com/doku.php?id=databse_schema) help :). This is database scheme diagram of OpenCart